# Preserve order of values with linq and ToLookup()

Tags: linq

While I'm pretty certain that the keys are unordered when returned from linq's ToLookup method, Is the order of **values** preserved?  I can't find any documentation that says one way or the other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The current implementation of `ToLookup()` does indeed preserve the order of the values (check the implementation of `Lookup<TKey,TElement>.Grouping<TKey,TElement>.Add()`), but I do not believe it is guaranteed to stay that way. To guarantee ordering, your best bet is probably to include the element's original index, perhaps using `Select`'s [with-index overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx), and then sort again.

Comment: Since this property of order stability is documented _and_ a LINQ default, it is _extremely_ likely to stay this way. However, it is easy to overlook that this is only guaranteed on _the result of `ToLookup()`_, **not for _any given_ `ILookup<TKey, TElement>`**. After all, anyone is free to use their own implementation of that interface. So you might fluently rely on the order stability, but you should not rely on it for any lookup received from another method. :)

Comment: @Timo: Preservation of order implies a knowledge of the ordering of elements prior to their generation. If you're receiving an `ILookup` from another method, you have no knowledge of the original order, so the point is moot.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior That... is an excellent point. 

Answer (score 16):

Yes. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToLookup__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__):

> The values within each group are in the same order as in `source`.

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are, look [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452507/linq-to-objects-does-groupby-preserve-order-of-elements) ILookup is derived from `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`. I believe the values are guaranteed to stay in order.