# Linq to Objects: does GroupBy preserve order of elements?

Tags: .net, linq, group-by

Does `Enumerable.GroupBy` from LINQ to Objects preserve order of elements in the groups?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserving order with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq)

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Found answer on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx): Yes.

> The `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`. Elements in a grouping are yielded **in the order they appear in source**.

Comment: Not that it is directly relevant to the question but as it may be a question on which people fall while finding things not well ordered it may be interested to note that it's not the case for PLINQ unless explicitely requested.

Comment: That documentation is only applicable to LINQ-to-objects. The same may not be true for specific implementations of LINQ-to-SQL, LINQ-to-XML, or LINQ-to-anything-else.

Comment: @aboveyou00 after hours trying to get the groups sorted by other fields than the group key, you saved my day with your comment. LINQ to MySql sorts the groups automagically by the group key! I've had to use ToList to bring the ordered query to local objects, then group over that. Thank you.