# Sorting output from Linq with group by

Tags: linq, sorting, group-by

The linq query below is not returning results that have been ordered by the sequence field in decending order. Instead the results are returned without regard to the orderby:

```
var qr = from l in reports.layouts
    where l.job == jobNumber
    orderby l.sequence descending
    group l by l.filename;
```

However the code below is able to return the results grouped by the filename field, and ordered decending by the sequence field:

```
var qr = reports.layouts
   .Where(l => l.job == jobNumber)
   .OrderBy(l => l.filename)
   .GroupBy(l => l.filename, (l, c) => c.OrderByDescending(x => x.sequence));
```

Can anyone offer any insight as to how the first query should be written to return the results in the desired descending sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping destroys the order.  Your two queries are not the same.

The first translates into something more like:

```
var qr = reports.layouts
   .Where(l => l.job == jobNumber)
   .OrderByDescending(l => l.sequence)
   .GroupBy(l => l.filename);
```

Since the GroupBy happens after the ordering, it effectively destroys the ordering.

Personally, this is one case where I find the method chain syntax you've used much more clear in terms of intent than an equivalent query syntax.

Comment: Seems not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452507/linq-to-objects-does-groupby-preserve-order-of-elements

Comment: @DavidB: That's true for LINQ to Objects, but not necessarily other LINQ sources.  See Queryable.GroupBy's docs, and notice that is NOT specified: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549270.aspx

Comment: Yes of course.  OP didn't specifiy what query source.  Since it's not a DataContext or ObjectContext or DBContext, I presumed LinqToObjects.  You are right - it's an assumption.

Comment: THanks for helping me understand what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

```
var qr =
  from l in reports.layouts
  where l.job == jobNumber
  group l by l.filename into g
  orderby g.Key descending
  select
    from x in g
    orderby x.sequence descending
    select x;
```

Comment: David B -- Thank you for the code sample. It certainly helps me understand what is necessary to make the query work in the query syntax vs the method syntax.