# how to check consecutive repeated numbers C#

Tags: c#, string

I'm fairly new to C# and I'm trying to accomplish this i have this string

> 15556677889

and i need it to be like this

> 132221

so basically count how many times a number is repeated and then generate a string with them.
any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
only when they are consecutive so

> 22211222

would be

> 323

Comment: `22211222` is `323` or `62`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We're glad you're here. Please read [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is likely to be voted down and closed because you haven't demonstrated any effort. If there's something *specific* you're stuck on, post what you've written and rephrase your post to ask that specific question.

Comment: Why not build a loop for every character within the string?

Comment: I mostly done c programming so i tried this

Comment: How would you do it on c? Show what you´ve tried so far.

Comment: `string a = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length-1;i++ )
            {
                if (s[i] == s[i + 1])
                {
                    a += s[i];
                    x=i;
                    while (s[x] == s[x + 1] && x <= s.Length - 1)
                    {
                        x++;
                    }
                    if (x>1)
                    a += x;              
                }
                else
                {
                    x = 1;
                }`
But i get string out of bound message :c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Altough there are some missing points in question (for ex, what is the output for `15556677889111111`), I would write it with linq

```
var output = string.Concat("15556677889".GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.Count()));
```

---

OUTPUT: `132221`

**EDIT**

After your edit I would write an extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupSequenceWhile<T>(this   IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, T, bool> condition) 
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    using (var en = seq.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (en.MoveNext())
        {
            var prev = en.Current;
            list.Add(en.Current);

            while (en.MoveNext())
            {
                if (condition(prev, en.Current))
                {
                    list.Add(en.Current);
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return list;
                    list = new List<T>();
                    list.Add(en.Current);
                }
                prev = en.Current;
            }

            if (list.Any())
                yield return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is the same

```
var output = string.Concat("15556677889"
                           .GroupSequenceWhile((c1,c2)=>c1==c2)
                           .Select(x => x.Count()));
```

Comment: You don´t need the concat-call

Comment: This won´t work if a number appears more then once in more then one group.

Comment: @Eser You should remove the initial solution, because it is incorrect, and leave only the after edit correct one with stream grouping

Comment: @Eser [Seems to be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452507/linq-to-objects-does-groupby-preserve-order-of-elements). Still it (the original solution) will fail when the same digits are repeated in different parts of the string.

Comment: @Eser And what does it produce for 22233222? Though at the moment of posting the matter of what to do with such sequences wasn't defined by the OP.

Comment: @Eser `string.Concat("33322333".GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.Count()))`? `62`. Okay, I don't insist. Perhaps I am being too obsessive-compulsive on that account. Good luck. And +1 for `GroupBy` that preserves the order - thought that was implementation defined.

Comment: @EugenePodskal you are missing the edited part of my answer... (BTW: All built-in linq methods preserve the original order.)

Comment: @Eser That what I have been trying to tell you - why do you need a **wrong answer at the top** of your post, when you have a **completely correct one at the bottom**? People are lazy - they may not read after the *EDIT* and just copy-paste the tiny LINQ string at the top. That's is obviously their problem, but still...

Comment: this worked thank you!

Comment: @EugenePodskal You may be correct but it reflects the original history of the question.... If someone in need is too lazy to read the answer completely he deserves funny results.