# How to remove duplicates in the middle

Tags: linq, enumerable

Given a sequence like below:-

```
var list = new[] {"1a", "1b", "1c", "1d", "2a", "3a", "4a", "4b", "5a", "6a", "7a", "7b", "8a"}.Select(x => new { P1 = x.Substring(0,1), P2 = x.Substring(1,1)});
```

I'd like to remove the duplicates in the "middle" to end up with:-

```
var expected = new[] {"1a", "1d", "2a", "3a", "4a", "4b", "5a", "6a", "7a", "7b", "8a"}.Select(x => new { P1 = x.Substring(0, 1), P2 = x.Substring(1, 1) });
```

So any repeats of more than two are stripped out. It's important that I get the first and last duplicate though.

Comment: You can use `GroupBy` since it preserves order (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452507/linq-to-objects-does-groupby-preserve-order-of-elements), or `Aggregate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that don't Aggregate and want a super short answer using closure here:

```
var data = new[] { "1a", "1b", "1c", "1d", "2a", "3a", "4a", "4b", "1e", "5a", "6a", "7a", "7b", "8a" };
char priorKey = ' ';
int currentIndex = 0;

var result2 = data.GroupBy((x) => x[0] == priorKey ? new { k = x[0], g = currentIndex } : new { k = priorKey = x[0], g = ++currentIndex })
    .Select(i => new[] { i.First(), i.Last() }.Distinct())
    .SelectMany(i => i).ToArray();
```

Hat Tip to @Slai for the code this is based on (I added a fix for the non-continuous group issue.)

---

Here is how to do it with Aggregate.
I didn't test all edge cases... just your test cases.

```
var list = new[] { "1a", "1b", "1c", "1d", "2a", "3a", "4a", "4b", "5a", "6a", "7a", "7b", "8a" }
           .Aggregate(new { result = new List<string>(), first = "", last = "" },
              (store, given) =>
              {
                var result = store.result;
                var first = store.first;
                var last = store.last;

                 if (first == "")
                  // this is the first one.
                  first = given;
                else
                {
                  if (first[0] == given[0])
                    last = given;
                  else
                  {
                    result.Add(first);
                    if (last != "")
                      result.Add(last);
                    first = given;
                    last = "";
                  }

                }
                 return new { result = result, first = first, last = last }; },
                 (store) => { store.result.Add(store.first); if (store.last != "") store.result.Add(store.last); return store.result; })
           .Select(x => new { P1 = x.Substring(0,1), P2 = x.Substring(1,1)});
```

I create an object to hold the list so far and the first and last known so far.

Then I just apply logic to remove the middle stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Group by the first character and take the first and last item of each group:

```
var list = "1a 1b 1c 1d 2a 3a 4a 4b 5a 6a 7a 7b 8a".Split();

var result = list.GroupBy(i => i[0])
    .Select(i => new[] { i.First(), i.Last() }.Distinct())
    .SelectMany(i => i).ToArray();

Debug.Print(string.Join("\", \"", result)); 
// { "1a", "1b", "1c", "1d", "2a", "3a", "4a", "4b", "5a", "6a", "7a", "7b", "8a" }
```

Comment: Your answer is more succinct than Hogans but it doesn't allow for repetition e.g.   var list = "1a 1b 1c 1d 2a 3a 4a 4b 1e 5a 6a 7a 7b 8a". That said I used your code in combination with https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/GroupAdjacent.cs to achieve my goal. Thanks for the pointer, I was thinking of GroupByUntil or something.

Comment: @user630190 I think you mean "splitting non-contiguous groups" when you say repetition.   so the example you gave needs to return both 1a 1d and later 1e.

Comment: @user630190 - see my answer for the fix.