# 'Smart' grouping with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings and I want to convert it to some kind of grouped list, whereby the values would be grouped by their location in the list (not normal grouping, but in a way, that the same items are in a group only if they are together). Consider the following example:

```
LinkedList<string> myList = new LinkedList<string>();
myList.AddLast("aaa");
myList.AddLast("aaa");
myList.AddLast("bbb");
myList.AddLast("bbb");
myList.AddLast("aaa");
myList.AddLast("aaa");
myList.AddLast("aaa");

LinkedList<MyTuple> groupedList = new LinkedList<MyTuple>();
groupedList.AddLast(new MyTuple("aaa", 2));
groupedList.AddLast(new MyTuple("bbb", 2));
groupedList.AddLast(new MyTuple("aaa", 3));
```

Can this transformation be done with LINQ or should I write the algorithm usual way with loops?

Comment: The second snippet isn't going to run as you're adding a value with the same key twice.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, edited the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extension method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478070/how-to-group-consecutive-similar-items-of-a-collection/2528167#2528167) does pretty much what you ask (Microsoft also provide an [implementation to group contiguous items in a sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138361.aspx)):

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> 
    GroupConsecutive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> set, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    var i = 0;
    var k = 0;
    var ranges = from e in set
                 let idx = ++i
                 let next = set.ElementAtOrDefault(idx)
                 let key = (predicate(e, next)) ? k : k++
                 group e by key into g
                 select g;
    return ranges;
}
```

You could use it as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    LinkedList<string> myList = new LinkedList<string>();
    myList.AddLast("aaa");
    myList.AddLast("aaa");
    myList.AddLast("bbb");
    myList.AddLast("bbb");
    myList.AddLast("aaa");
    myList.AddLast("aaa");
    myList.AddLast("aaa");
    IGrouping<int,string> ggg;

    var groups=myList.GroupConsecutive((a,b)=>a==b);

    ILookup<string,int> lookup=groups.ToLookup(g=>g.First(),g=>g.Count());

    foreach(var x in lookup["aaa"])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x); //outputs 2 then 3
    }
    foreach(var x in lookup["bbb"])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x); //outputs 2
    }

}
```

Notice that the final container is an [ILookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx) which behaves a little like a Dictionary, but allows one to store multiple values against a single key.

Comment: As written, `GroupConsecutive` calls the comparator with the 'default' the last time.  That seems bad (especially in my case as it was crashing with a NullReferenceException because my comparator didn't expect it.)

Comment: @ScottStafford : I'd go with the linked MS solution here. I've used it with much success.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the Dictionary.  A dictionary is associative (i.e.: each key must point to one and one only) and is by nature unordered.  You'd need to use something else for that data structure. It wouldn't be terribly hard though!

**Edit**

A `List<Tuple<string, int>>` should do the trick:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> structure = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
structure.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(myList[0], 1);
for(int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++ )
{
    if( myList[i] == structure[structure.Count-1].Key )
    {
        structure[structure.Count-1].Value += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        structure.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(myList[i], 1);
    }
}
```

After that you should (untested!) have what you're looking for.

**Edit (one more thought)**

While it may be possible with linq (using TakeWhile and counts...), I still think it makes more sense to use a loop here, it's simple.  Someone more brilliant than I could try and work with Linq.

Comment: Say, a `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`?

Comment: I think that "something else" container already exists with the ILookup interface (see my answer)

Comment: @spender: does ILookup preserve the mutual order of the groups? (E.g. if I have aabbccaa, will I be able to find out where the second group of a's is with respect to the others?)

Comment: I can't find any docs to say one way or the other. My simplistic test says yes, but unfortunately simple observation cannot be relied upon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189982/preserve-order-of-values-with-linq-and-tolookup/1190034#1190034 indicates that it does, but even this does not guarantee that it always will.